# Difference between extraterrestrial and alien?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

What is the difference between **extraterrestrial** and **alien** in terms of the usage of these two words?

Comment: Context and research please.

Comment: There is a vast difference, depending on your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extraterrestrial very specifically refers to something which is not from planet Earth. Alien is a more general word which can be used in many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Not much. They are essentially synonymous.

The only substantial difference is that, in addition to referring to *a being or creature from outer space*, **alien** can also mean *a foreigner, someone who isn't a naturalized citizen* (noun) or *odd, distasteful* (adjective). **Extraterrestrial** doesn't have these additional meanings.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=extraterrestrial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#newwindow=1&q=alien%20define)

Comment: So, what is a human born on Mars?

Comment: Confused and lonely?